# Can I use a vector for bounds input for the linspace function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an Nx2 matrix A where each row is an upper bound and lower bound pair and I would like to create an MxN matrix B for which each column is a linspace of M elements from the upper and lower bounds in the coresponding row of A.

For example:

```
A = [   2  10  ;
       20 100  ;
       30  50  ;
      0.1 0.5  ]
```

with a value of 5 for M should give the result:

```
B = [  2  20 30 0.1 ; 
       4  40 35 0.2 ;
       6  60 40 0.3 ;
       8  80 45 0.4 ;
      10 100 50 0.5 ]
```

I can do this easily with a loop:

```
B = zeros(M,size(A,1));
for i = 1:size(A,1)
  B(:,i) = linspace(A(i,1),A(i,2),M)';
end
```

but I would like to know a more "Matlab-y" way if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate that result with two calls of `bsxfun`, but I'm not sure if that's Matlaby enough :D

```
A = [   2  10  ;
        20 100  ;
        30  50  ;
        0.1 0.5  ]
M = 5;
B = bsxfun(@plus, A(:, 1), ...
    bsxfun(@times, A(:, 2)-A(:, 1), linspace(0, 1, M)))';
```

This performs better here, with R2016b.

```
nTest = 10000;
d = 1000;
M = 50;
A = rand(d, 2)*100;
tic
for i=1:nTest
    B1 = bsxfun(@plus, A(:, 1), ...
        bsxfun(@times, A(:, 2)-A(:, 1), linspace(0, 1, M)))';
end
toc
tic
for j=1:nTest
    B2 = zeros(M,size(A,1));
    for i = 1:size(A,1)
        B2(:,i) = linspace(A(i,1),A(i,2),M)';
    end
end
toc
maxDiff = max(max(abs(B1-B2)))
```

Results:

> Elapsed time is 1.380361 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 9.965803 seconds.
>
> maxDiff =
> 2.8422e-14

Comment: measuring the execution time might be a bit misleading if the variable-to-fill is not allocated beforehand. See [preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)

Comment: @max I'm (guskenny83's) not changing the size of matrix inside the loop. Actually I also included preallocation overhead in timing.

Comment: oh yes, I have overlooked this. Just filling it with zeros shouldn't cause such a difference in time oO striking

Comment: As of R2016b you can instead of `bsxfun` use operators to do implicit expansion: `(A(:, 1)+(A(:, 2)-A(:, 1)) .* linspace(0, 1, M)).'`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using [cumsum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
B = cumsum(repmat((A(:, 2)-A(:, 1))/(M-1),1,M),2).';
```